# A twitter javascript library that shows retweets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

So far I was using [twitterjs](http://code.google.com/p/twitterjs/), but it doesn't show **retweets** from my timeline. So I'm just looking for an alternative able to show retweets.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personnaly use *jTweetsAnywhere*, which is very featureful and quite easy to deploy. It depends on jQuery and does show retweets when I display my timeline.

You can download it and read the documentation here :

http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/

Comment: This is a truly awesome JS Twitter Library. Worked like a charm, has tons of features, nice demos, good documentation AND supports localization. Wow.

Comment: Amazing find. I've tried a few twitter libraries and even ended up writing my own. Stumbled across this post and looked at your link. So much better that anything I've seen or come up with. Thanks!